# Is the common ForkJoin pool system wide or per JVM Instance

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

I want to know if the `forkjoinpool.commonpool()` is a OS system wide share thread pool or a per JVM instance shared thread pool?

Comment: It's per JVM. Two JVMs can't share a thread. If they could, those wouldn't be threads anymore, by definition of a Thread.

Comment: As @JBNizet mentioned it's per JVM. But, [H2O](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) supports shared `ForkJoinPool`s and [Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast) supports shared `Executor`s